# does there exist a continuous function $f$ such that $l(f) = 4$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

for a continuous function $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ I have a linear functional $l(f) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin t) f(t) \ dt$ which I have found a bound: $|l(f)| \leq 4 \|f\|_c$ I am asked if it is possible to find a $f$ such that $\|l(f)\| = 4$ which I have reduced to figuring out if I can find an $f$ such that $l(f) = 4$. I think it's not possible, but I can't ifnd a contradiction

Comment: I have edited my post regarding the integrand, and yes that's the $\|f\|_c$ sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you don't insist on continuity, what bounded measurable function(s) give you $l(f) = 4$ when $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty} \leqslant 1$?

Comment: What is $\|f\|_c$?

Comment: @DanielFischer if I take f(t) = -1 on $-\pi \leq t \leq 0$ and $1$ on$ 0 < t \leq \pi$ I guess that gives me the result, but not continuous

Comment: @anomaly $\|f\|_c = \text{max}_{t \in [-\pi,\pi]} |f(t)|$

Comment: @rexel Right. And if there is a nondegenerate interval $(a,b)$ with $\lvert f(t)\rvert < 1$ for $t\in (a,b)$?

Comment: You are not stating the problem correctly. It's trivial to make $l(f)=4.$ You want  $\|f\| = 1$ *and* $l(f) = 4.$

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure what you mean by this statement, but are you saying to construct a function which is $1$ and $-1$ as before, but make it continuous by connecting a line between where it becomes discontinuous? If so, I can show that $l(f) = 4$ here, but the limit of it will not be continuous. Is this sufficient?

Comment: If you have $\lvert f(t)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and there are $-\pi \leqslant a < b \leqslant \pi$ such that $\lvert f(t)\rvert < 1$ for $t\in (a,b)$, can you have $l(f) = 4$ then?

Comment: I want to say no, but I am not sure how it follows from my previous assertion.

Comment: Let's try differently. Suppose $\lVert f\rVert_c \leqslant 1$. Then you have $f(t)\cdot \sin t \leqslant \lvert \sin t\rvert$ for all $t$. What can you say about $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \bigl(\lvert \sin t\rvert - f(t)\sin t\bigr)\,dt\,?$$

Comment: it's non negative

Comment: I have solved it. thanks.